# How do you handle dynamic CSS in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, dynamic-css

I'm in need of some CSS for a WordPress plugin which are dynamic and would like to know what is the best or the most common method. I'm currently using method two but have problems with IE9. So I thought there could be a better solution for dynamic CSS and came up with these:

### 1.) include a style block with the `wp_head` hook

**Pro:**

- No extra server request

**Contra:**

- Depending on the size a lot data on each page
- not so pretty
- not cacheable

### 2.) Use `admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=my_css')` in a link tag

**Pro:**

- create CSS on-the-fly (and cache it with Transient API)
- uses `wp_enqueue_style`
- cacheable with expire headers

**Contra**

- requires to load `wp-load.php`
- doesn't work on IE9 ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997674/ie9-doesnt-allow-dynamic-style-with-php-and-content-type-text-css))

### 3.) create a CSS file on changes

**Pro**

- fast
- no need to load the whole WordPress (`wp-load.php`)

**Contra**

- not really dynamic
- require write rules for certain folders
- possible out of date or missing cause of script issues or missing permissions

I don't like method one cause the style is not required on every page and method two doesn't work on IE9.

Should I go with the third one or are the any disadvantages with it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you thought of using javascript?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "dynamic"? How dynamic is it - do things change on each request? When the user changes something in the backend? Every day? Every week?

Comment: @Pekka changes are only made if user hits save on the settings page and made changes in a certain textarea

Comment: @Ibu Plugin should work with JS disabled so no option in my case

Comment: Would it not make more sense to write the changes into a static file then? You'd save a lot of hassle that way (If Wordpress plugins are allowed to do that, not sure)

Comment: That's the point, it's not guaranteed that I have write permissions

Comment: You should always have access to the uploads folder (that's the point of it, I think) so write your static files there.  For #2, can you add the appropriate header(s) when serving the ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are somewhat limited with PHP not having a built-in persistent cache. If you can guarantee that you will have `memcached`, `APC`, or even file write access, then you can use any of these methods to cache your CSS, and retrieve it using a key. You would not need to use `wp-load.php` to do so, thus your performance would be improved over having to load all the plugins, etc.

That said, your dynamic CSS *should* work in IE9 assuming you set `header('Content-type: text/css');` before you output the CSS, per the Microsoft article [MIME-Handling Change: text/css](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

All that said, you could try a hybrid approach of #1 and #2 - it sounds like #3 is out if you can'g guarantee that you have file write permissions. To implement, just detect the `user-agent` of the requesting browser, and set up a single function to output your CSS. If it **is not** IE9, you can include the stylesheet using `admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=my_css')` and call your output from the hooked function, and if it **is** IE9 you can include the stylesheet in the header by calling the function from a hook to `wp_head`. This way you are able to cache the CSS for most clients, and work around for IE - your cons about page size, etc are valid... but it's IE9.

As long as you are able to cache the CSS per client, then you are typically looking at only one extra request to `wp-load.php` which shouldn't be too great of a performance hit.

You can check for IE9 using `if (false!==strpos('MSIE 9;', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))`

Comment: I guess this is the way to go. Never thought about this kind of approach. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've created a library called [wp-dynamic-css](https://github.com/askupasoftware/wp-dynamic-css) that allows you to generate CSS from dynamic content.

The library allows you to use a special syntax to represent variables inside your CSS file.

This is how it can be used:

```
// 1. Load the library
require_once 'wp-dynamic-css/bootstrap.php';

// 2. Enqueue the stylesheet (using an absolute path, not URL)
wp_dynamic_css_enqueue( 'my-dynamic-style', 'path/to/my-style.css' );

// 3. Set the callback function (used to convert variables to actual values)
function my_dynamic_css_callback( $var_name )
{
   return get_theme_mod($var_name);
}
wp_dynamic_css_set_callback( 'my-dynamic-style', 'my_dynamic_css_callback' );
```

Now let's say you have a file called `my-style.css` with this code:

```
body {
   background-color: $body_bg_color;
}
```

If, for example, calling `get_theme_mod('body_bg_color')` returns the value `#fff`, then `my-style.css` will be compiled to:

```
body {
   background-color: #fff;
}
```